# Ubuntu dirs got locked due to web server starting up

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, mysql, xampp, lamp

I am using **Ubuntu Studio** 19.04 (latest version).

Every time I install XAMMP or LAMP server on my machine and restart I find all my directories locked except the those in file system **partition**

> my hard disk is partitioned and I but ubuntu file system alone in this partition to aviod lossing data as I'm not so good using linux yet

I'm not using root acount, **yet** when I run the server: the root alert appears in my system file navigator tell I stop all processes of the server.

[Screenshot img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqkOE.png)

**Last time** I tried `chown` & `chmod` solutions found on web for ordenary ubuntu but no thing changed **but** the GUI corrupted.

**Now** I run the server as I need it but I need a solution for the lock on dirs
I can't use my files anyway

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What locked dirs are a concern?

Comment: see the pic above..
Seems that server mysql uses root access without enabling root.. but I want to stop that.. as it lock all users from using any thing except root.. which is not a good at all idea while using ubuntu studio.. I hope to find out how to stop that

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your pictures looks normal and correct.   Some folders/files are specifically designed to be only accessible by root because to not do so would be a security fail.   Without further information I can only make suppositions, hopefully the below might be of help -

- The described problem does not appear to have anything to do with the web server or LAMP.
- The problem does not appear to be related to your hard drive partitioning, rather to an external volume.  (/media is "[a mount point for removable media](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT)")
- The issue you are most likely having relates to an external hard drive or USB key being in the system at startup and being mounted with the permissions of the root.   I'll focus more on this below.

While most UNIX based filesystems have support for Unix user and group permissions, many filesystems from the Windows world don't.  Of specific note are "FAT" based filesystems common on external hard drives and USB keys.   **This means that there is no way to ascribe ownership to a file on one of these drives**.   There are, however, work-arrounds -

1. Reformat the filesystem so it is a Posix (ie unix/Linux) compliant one.  Reformatting the filesystem will cause it to loose the stored data, so back it up first, and the new disk will not work in Windows systems because Windows cant by default read EXT filesystems.
2. Try unplugging the drive and plugging it back in again when logged in.
3. When a Windows based filesystem is mounted, the OS can assign it a set of permissions.   You can change the permissions associated with the filesystem, for example by making all files read/write/execute and/or changing the owner.  This is not particularly secure, but is particularly convenient.  Unfortunately the details of how exactly you do this depends on how the disk is mounted.   This could either require changes in /etc/fstab if its a permanent mount, or playing with udev rules to identify the drive and set the permissions if its being handled dynamically.

It probably does not help you, but if you the device is always the same, and you know the current block device name (you can usually find it with a df command and get the appropriate line) you can do the following:

1. sudo blkid /dev/sdX?    (Make a note of the uuid)
2. sudo mkdir /mnt/extdisk (Make a new path to mount the drive)
3. Add a line to /etc/fstab (as root) along the following lines:

--

```
   UUID=XXXXXXXX /mnt/extdisk vfat  umask=000 0 1
```

This will in theory mount the drive as /mnt/extdisk in such a way that any user of the system can read, write and run anything on it.